# Which is better in SQL lots of small query's or one big query

Tags: php, sql

In SQL which is better, a loop of query's with smaller results returned or one query on the whole table and just store this in an array that I can query instead.

I'm expecting some rows to be returned multiple times using the small query way, and there is a possibility of the number of small query's being 1 or 2 sometimes but for arguments sake lets say 10 small query's.

Comment: Run a benchmark and you'll see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 big query will generally (almost always) be faster because SQL Server will optimize for the appropriate data access. E.g., the optimizer may elect to use a different index for the big query, or even a table scan. Using a series of small queries, when what you really want is the larger data set, hamstrings SQL Server's optimizer.

Also, it seems that you understand that the smaller queries will result in redundant data retrieval.

And finally, there's the issue of connection/reconnection, and multiple parsing of the smaller queries, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for :)